# no rule to make target while compiling elastix binaries

Tags: cmake, itk, elastix

I am trying to compile source code from Elastic binaries. I am using ITK and CMAKE. I am able to compile the code, however when I navigate to the build directory and run make install I get the following error

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/Users/tony/ITK_DIR/lib/libitkdouble-conversion-4.13.a', needed by 'bin/elastix'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5668: Core/CMakeFiles/elastix.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Here is some of my makefile code. I'm new to this so if any more information is needed please request it and I will provide it

```
.PHONY : default_target

# The main recursive all target
all:

.PHONY : all

# The main recursive preinstall target
preinstall:

.PHONY : preinstall

# The main recursive clean target
clean:

.PHONY : clean

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /private/var/folders/h7/c6g9qc8j25l92b58yr_jbc2h0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/BE140EBD-E4FD-4FE0-8DAA-7526DF6251A7/d/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /private/var/folders/h7/c6g9qc8j25l92b58yr_jbc2h0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/BE140EBD-E4FD-4FE0-8DAA-7526DF6251A7/d/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/tony/Downloads/InsightToolkit-4.13.2

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /Users/tony/ITK_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure ITK to use system double conversion? If so, you might be interested in the patch in this [PR](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/pull/969). If not, you could ask about your problem on [Elastix forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elastix-imageregistration).